# Use maps in Go templates

Tags: dictionary, go

I need to use a map in template, however, the syntax is not correct

```
                <tr>
                        <td>India</td>
                        <td>{{$val.Agent.Imei}}</td>
                        <td>{{$val.Jid}}</td>
                        <td>{{.LoginTimeMap[$val.Jid]}}
                    </tr>
```

it saids the [] in {{.LoginTimeMap[$val.Jid]}} is unexpected bad character U+005B '[' in command

Please Help

Answer (score 5):

In templates, use `index` instead of `[]`.

http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions

> index
>
> Returns the result of indexing its first argument by the
> following arguments. Thus "index x 1 2 3" is, in Go syntax,
> x[1][2][3]. Each indexed item must be a map, slice, or array.

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/YuJX5A1CB2).

Comment: Thanks but now it said <.TimeMap>: TimeMap is not a field of struct type couchbaseHandler.ChannelData

I think it is because I {{range $index, $val := .DevicesData}} {{$val.Jid}} {{index .TimeMap $val.Jid}}      {{end}} .  I think TimeMap is within the DeviceData that cause the probelm.

Comment: @PeterHon that is another error, unrelated to the one you've asked about. Please read the `text/template` package documentation, it should answer all your questions.